# Why does a contact show up in call log, but not in contact application?

Tags: contacts, call-history

I have a friend with a Sony Xperia Z3 compact experiencing a problem where a contact is accessible from the call log, but not from the contacts application.

- Contact does not show up in contacts application.
- In the call log, there is an option for view contact, but not for add contact. When viewing the contact, there is a manually added note.
- Synchronization of Google Contacts is on.

How do I get the contact to show in the contacts application normally?